# MaxScale with multicluster setup

Tags: mariadb, replication, database-replication, master-slave, maxscale

I've been working on some High Availability scenario's for some database servers and inspected MaxScale & HAProxy and both seem very interesting but the problem is as follows.
When setting up MaxScale everything went well until I discovered that I don't see a way to create multiple clusters on the same MaxScale instance but this is a necessity for the amount of database servers that will have to be controlled using one MaxScale instance.

Is there any way to implement multiple clusters when setting up MaxScale or is this just something that isn't implemented in MaxScale?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you attempting to use multiple database clusters with one MaxScale instance? If so, just define more servers, monitor, services and listeners to define them.

Comment: @markusjm Yes, that's exactly my goal, it would be a whole lot (5 - 10) clusters connecting to one MaxScale instance and it would be up to this maxscale instance to divide the traffic depending on where the request was designed to go
In my test environment I currently have a Master-Slave setup but I wouldn't know how to define a second cluster with a Master-Slave setup in MaxScale
Is there something specific that must be defined or not?

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple clusters with one MaxScale, just define multiple servers, monitors, services and listeners. Here is an example of one cluster being used as a service:

```
[server1]
type=server
address=127.0.0.1
port=3000
protocol=MariaDBBackend

[server2]
type=server
address=127.0.0.1
port=3001
protocol=MariaDBBackend

[Cluster-1-Monitor]
type=monitor
module=mariadbmon
servers=server1,server2
user=maxuser
passwd=maxpwd
monitor_interval=5000

[Cluster-1-Router]
type=service
router=readwritesplit
servers=server1,server2
user=maxuser
passwd=maxpwd

[Cluster-1-Listener]
type=listener
service=Cluster-1-Router
protocol=MariaDBClient
port=4006
```

This would expose the read-write splitting service on port 4006 that would do read-write splitting over the servers `server1` and `server2`.

To define another one, just add:

- The servers that define the cluster
- A monitor for monitoring the servers
- A service that uses the servers
- A listener that connects to the service

This way you can expose multiple ports that connect to different clusters. For example, one cluster could listen on port 4006 and another on 4007. These two could then be used to connect two different applications to two different clusters.

Comment: Alright, when I look at this it should work expect for 1 issue
The clusters I'm using have a multimaster setup and a readwritesplit isn't possible, is there any way to define a type of router that accepts multimaster setups?

Comment: This mainly depends on whether you still want writes to go to one place or multiple places. Look into the `readconnroute` router if you want to spread writes across all nodes. Most likely you would still be able to use `readwritesplit` even if you have a multi-master setup. You can look at the various types of monitors MaxScale comes with and see if your cluster type is supported: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-enterprise/maxscale-22-monitors/